# Wrong number of columns at line ##

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, valueerror

i have csv files in a folder name called stock_csv100. Each file in that folder has 7 columns named date, price, open, high, low, Vol and change%. So i want to access every file and take only the price column(second column) into another new seperated csv files. Ex Dialog_stock100 (has 7 columns) should have another seperate file that has only one column(price column). Here is the code i tried, but it gives me an error.

```
import numpy as np
import glob

filenames = glob.glob('stock_csv100/*.csv')
filenames = filenames[0:3]

for f in filenames:
    print(f)

date_OS, price_OS, open_OS, high_OS, low_OS, vol_OS, change_OS = np.**loadtxt**(f,
                                                                            delimiter=',',
                                                                            unpack=True,
                                                                            dtype='str')

print(f)
x = 0
for eachDate in date_OS[x]:
    saveLine = price_OS[x] + '\n'
    saveFile = open('newCSVclosingPrice' + x + '.csv', 'a')
    saveFile.write(saveLine)
    saveFile.close()
    x += 1
```

the error i get is;

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/IdeaPad/PycharmProjects/gedaraweda1/lll.py", line 13, in
>   
>       dtype='str')   File "C:\Users\IdeaPad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py",
>   line 1092, in loadtxt
>       for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):   File "C:\Users\IdeaPad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py",
>   line 1016, in read_data
>       % line_num) ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 2

I changed the loadtxt into genfromtxt and when i use that, i get this error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/IdeaPad/PycharmProjects/gedaraweda1/lll.py", line 13, in
>   
>       dtype='str')   File "C:\Users\IdeaPad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py",
>   line 2014, in genfromtxt
>       raise ValueError(errmsg) ValueError: Some errors were detected !
>       Line #2 (got 8 columns instead of 7)
>       Line #3 (got 8 columns instead of 7)

Comment: please edit or accept the edit to your question, I'm unable to read with this format. In future, use code format correctly

Comment: ohh sorry, i'm kinda new here :/

Comment: that's okay! just edit it and people would be able to answer you better :) also look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: did you try the pandas library ?

Comment: yeah, unfortunately pandas doesn't have CSE(Colombo Stock Exchange) data

Comment: pandas no, your excel file yes. Try with `pandas.read_csv()`